# How to escape strings in bash script

Tags: string, bash, escaping

I am running a bash script that calls mysql. The password ist not correctly transmitted, I guess I have to escape some special chars, like the hash or the dollar sign?

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=myuser
PASS="#mypass$"

# ... call mysql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `"..."` is already the correct thing to do, but the `$` needs to be escaped (`\$`) if it isn't followed by an "invalid" character. However you also need to make sure to always have the variable in quotation marks as well, as in:

```
somecommand -p "$PASS"
```

Comment: __`Using "..." is already the correct thing to do`__
I'm confused. Is "# ..." a special sequence in bash?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "\" before the character that you are trying to escape.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=myuser
PASS="#mypass\$"

# ... call mysql
```

Comment: @mit: You could also just change to single quotes which prevents the expansion of the contents. `PASS='#mypass$'` Beware the security implications of passing passwords on the command line.