# How to escape space in bash script from inline if?

Tags: bash

I know that similar questions have been asked and answered before on stackoverflow (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373182/escaping-space-in-bash-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220325/how-to-escape-strings-in-bash-script)) but so far I haven't been able to figure it out for my particular case.

I'm trying to create a script that adds the `-v` flag only if the variable `something` is equal to `"true"` (what I'm trying to do is to mount the current folder as a volume located at `/src` in the Docker container):

```
docker run --name image-name `if [ "${something}" == "true" ]; then echo "-v $PWD:/src"; fi` ....
```

The problem is that `$PWD` may contain spaces and if so my script won't work. I've also tried assigning `"$PWD"` to an intermediate variable but it still doesn't work:

```
temp="$PWD"
docker run --name image-name `if [ "${something}" == "true" ]; then echo "-v $temp:/src"; fi` ....
```

If I run:

```
docker run --name image-name -v "$PWD":/src ....
```

from plain bash (without using my script) then everything works.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: This is essentially [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). So the answer is you don't. You don't do this. You use an array or similar.

Comment: Welcome to the space-in-filenames-hell.  How about a nice symlink pointing to the darn file name and containing no spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array.

```
docker_args=()
if something; then
    docker_args+=( -v "$PWD/src" )
fi
docker run --blah "${docker_args[@]}" …
```

Don't have arrays? Use `set` (in a function, so it doesn't affect outer scope).

Generally:

```
knacker() {
    if something; then
        set -- -v "$PWD:/src" "$@"
    fi
    crocker "$@"
}
knacker run --blah
```

But some commands (like docker, git, etc) need special treatment because of their two-part command structure.

```
slacker() {
    local cmd="$1"
    shift
    if something; then
        set -- -v "$PWD:/src" "$@"
    fi
    docker "$cmd" "$@"
}
slacker run --blah
```

Comment: Beats me.  By seconds ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using the array way):

```
declare -a cmd=()
cmd+=(docker run --name image-name)
if [ "${something}" = "true" ]
then
  cmd+=(-v "$PWD:/src")
fi
"${cmd[@]}"
```